# TypeScript: inherit from Array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript1.4

I'm trying to create a rich data model for an AngularJS application and I would like for my model to inherit from `Array<BaseModel>`. I haven't found a way to do this (with confidence) yet.

In pseudocode this would be something like:

```
// NOT REAL CODE. DOES NOT WORK
class BaseModel {}
class Person extends BaseModel {}
class People extends Array<Person> {
    constructor(private promise:Promise) { }
    $unwrap(promise) { 
        promise.then((response) => {
            response.data.map((person) => {
                this.push(new Person(person));
            });
        });
    }
    static $load() {
        /* do some ajaxy thing and unwrap the promise right onto the 
           the new instance of this rich model */

        return new People(promise);
    }
}
```

The reason I would like something like this is that now I can bind this model directly to my view and get updates on the fly.

Any thoughts on extending from Array?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Have you encountered a problem with your design?

Comment: Yes, the question is: "How do I inherit from Array<T> in TypeScript". The design works quite well: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHbWRFpbma4). I've released several projects using this technique in JS. I want to move to TypeScript from JS and would like to take this pattern with me.

Comment: Ok, so have you tried anything? Looks like you've laid out an idea above. How did it go? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ah, well yes, this code above does not work. ```Array<Person>``` is an interface and not a class, hence I cannot extend my ```People``` class with this interface. This is pseudo-code outlining the general idea. It is not a solution but a "I would love it if something like this would be possible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point it time it is not possible to inherit from Array in TypeScript. It is best to unwrap into a public array field and use this field to bind to the UI. It resolves into the same functionality and remove the necessity of inheriting from Array.